# R Cluster Package Error Daisy() function long vectors (argument 11) are not supported in .C

Tags: r, csv, amazon-ec2, cluster-analysis, r-daisy

Trying to convert a `data.frame` with numeric, nominal, and NA values to a dissimilarity matrix using the `daisy` function from the `cluster` package in R. My purpose involves creating a dissimilarity matrix before applying k-means clustering for customer segmentation. The `data.frame` has 133,153 rows and 36 columns. Here's my machine.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

**How can I fix the daisy warning?**

Since the Windows computer has 3 Gb RAM, I increased the virtual memory to 100GB hoping that would be enough to create the matrix - it didn't work. I still got a couple errors about the memory. I've looked into other R packages for solving the memory problem, but they don't work. I cannot use the `bigmemory` with the `biganalytics` package because it only accepts numeric matrices. The `clara` and `ff` packages also accept only numeric matrices.

CRAN's `cluster` package suggests the gower similarity coefficient as a distance measure before applying k-means. The gower coefficient takes numeric, nominal, and NA values.

```
Store1 <- read.csv("/Users/scdavis6/Documents/Work/Client1.csv", head=FALSE)
df <- as.data.frame(Store1)
save(df, file="df.Rda")
library(cluster)
daisy1 <- daisy(df, metric = "gower", type = list(ordratio = c(1:35)))
#Error in daisy(df, metric = "gower", type = list(ordratio = c(1:35))) :
#long vectors (argument 11) are not supported in .C
```

**EDIT: I have RStudio lined to Amazon Web Service's (AWS) r3.8xlarge with 244Gbs of memory and 32 vCPUs. I tried creating the daisy matrix on my computer, but did not have enough RAM. **

**EDIT 2: I used the clara function for clustering the dataset. **

```
#50 samples
clara2 <- clara(df, 3, metric = "euclidean", stand = FALSE, samples = 50,
                rngR = FALSE, pamLike = TRUE)
```

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use algorithms that do *not* require O(n^2) memory, if you have a lot of data. Swapping to disk will *kill* performance, this is not a sensible option.

Instead, try either to reduce your data set size, or use index acceleration to avoid the O(n^2) memory cost. (And it's not only O(n^2) memory, but also O(n^2) distance computations, which will take a long time!)

Comment: How would I do index acceleration? Load the data in MySQL first before creating the daisy matrix? There's a RMySQL package, I'll look into that.

Comment: No, don't even think of touching MySQL. I haven't used daisy, so I don't know *if* it can be index accelerated. You can't just throw magic index acceleration at everything. There is no "RmakeMagicIndexAcceleration" package for this very reason. The methods and implementations must be *designed* to be accelerated this way, and it looks as if this daisy implementation is designed to compute an upper diagonal matrix.

Comment: ELKI has a lot of index accelerated algorithms, but I did not see daisy on this list. And it's not R.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I decided to use Amazon Web Services because of the RAM requirement. Thank you for showing ELKI.

Comment: even with the AWS server, I still got an error about the dataset being too large. Maybe I will reduce the dataset size with random sampling and cross-validate the result?

Comment: I'm not surprised. Yes, with many algorithms the result on a large enough sample will be essentially the same. But other than that, don't use R. Much of the stuff in R is designed to work on matrixes, and that will need O(n^2) memory; and you cannot afford buying quadratic amounts of memory on the long run.
Also, working on a sample first allows you to figure out if your approach works at all, before scaling it up.

Comment: I tested by putting a different dataset with 15k observations (dataset above had 50k) in a daisy matrix and did k-medoid clustering. I did not have any errors, but the two steps took over an hour. I agree that testing on a smaller dataset is important to check for errors, but I need to cluster every customer in the dataset. What options do I have left?

Comment: You may be able to generalize the results in O(n) to the complete data set. See e.g. CLARA clustering. It runs k-medoids on a sample only. Then assignes the full data set to these medoids. It's O(n) if you can affort to choose a small enough sampling rate, whereas PAM probably is O(n^3) or so. Oh, and you can try to use *index acceleration*, which for some algorithms can yield massive speedups. I've clustered 100k in a few minutes with ELKI; indexes helped tremendously.

Comment: @Anony-Mouse, I looked at the CLARA function and it requires a numerical matrix. Seems like ELKI is the only option left.

Comment: CLARA should not require a full distance matrix `data matrix or data frame, each row corresponds to an observation`; this is not a n^2 distance matrix, but just the data.frame you already have.

Comment: I tried using CLARA and it worked without AWS. Now the problem is finding the command to see all observations assigned to each medoid.