# Error in clusplot function in R: Missing values were displaced by median of corresponding variables

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

My purpose involves creating a plot showing the results of the `CLARA` clustering algorithm in `R` using `clusplot`. I cannot get the `clusplot` function to plot anything.

**Problem:** Error on the `clusplot` function.

My `data.frame` called `frame` has 300 observations of 35 variables with categorical and missing values. I showed the first 5 rows of the dataset to save space.

My Machine:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)
```

My Code:

Data Description

```
#View data.frame
> head(Store2, n=5)

  user_id      Age      Gender   HouseholdIncome MaritalStatus Discount.Shopper
1   12945      <NA>     Male             <NA>           <NA>
2   12947      <NA>     Male             <NA>           <NA>
3   12990      <NA>     <NA>             <NA>           <NA>
4   13160      25-34    Male        100k-125k         Single
5   13195      <NA>     Male         75k-100k         Single

  PresenceofChildren HomeOwnerStatus HomeMarketValue Occupation
1               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>       <NA>
2               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>       <NA>
3               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>       <NA>
4                 No            Rent       350k-500k       <NA>
5                 No            Rent        500k-1mm       <NA>

                  Education ZipCode HighNetWorth LengthofResidence ArtsCrafts
1                      <NA>      NA         <NA>              <NA>         NA
2                      <NA>      NA         <NA>              <NA>         NA
3                      <NA>      NA         <NA>              <NA>         NA
4 Completed Graduate School   60657          Yes           2 Years         NA
5         Completed College   60614         <NA>           2 Years         NA

  Automotive BabyProductBuyer Beauty Blogging Books Business CharitableDonors
1         NA               NA     NA       NA    NA       NA               NA
2         NA               NA     NA       NA    NA       NA               NA
3         NA               NA     NA       NA    NA       NA               NA
4         NA               NA     NA       NA    NA       NA               NA
5       TRUE               NA     NA       NA    NA       NA               NA

  Cooking DiscountShopper HealthWellness HighEndBrandBuyer HomeGarden
1      NA              NA             NA                NA         NA
2      NA              NA             NA                NA         NA
3      NA              NA             NA                NA         NA
4      NA              NA             NA                NA         NA
5      NA              NA             NA                NA         NA

  HomeImprovement LuxuryGoods MagazineBuyer NewsCurrentEvents OutdoorAdventure Pets
1              NA          NA            NA                NA               NA   NA
2              NA          NA            NA                NA               NA   NA
3              NA          NA            NA                NA               NA   NA
4              NA          NA            NA                NA               NA   NA
5              NA          NA          TRUE                NA               NA   NA

  Sports Technology Travel
1     NA         NA     NA
2     NA         NA     NA
3     NA         NA     NA
4     NA       TRUE     NA
5     NA         NA     NA
```

Clustering

```
#Load library
library(cluster)
#Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(2)
#CLARA algorithm with 3 clusters and 5 samples of 60 
clara1 <- clara(frame, 3, metric = "gower", stand = FALSE, samples = 5,
      sampsize = (60), medoids.x = TRUE, keep.data = TRUE, 
      rngR = TRUE, pamLike = TRUE)
#Cluster plot of data
> clusplot(clara1, main = "CLARA Results", labels = 5)
 #Error in princomp.default(x, scores = TRUE, cor = ncol(x) != 2) : 
  #cannot use 'cor = TRUE' with a constant variable
```

**EDIT:** I mistakenly used the `Euclidean` distance measure instead of `Gower`.

Other threads recommend the `Gower` distance function for datasets with mixed values.

[Hierarchical clustering with mixed data type](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15287/hierarchical-clustering-with-mixed-type-data-what-distance-similarity-to-use/15313#15313)

According to this link, missing values in `Gower` are allowed.

[Computes the Gower's Distance](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/StatMatch/docs/gower.dist)

**EDIT 2:** I checked the `CLARA` function results and all the rows correspond to one of the three clusters. The `CLARA` function is working correctly. Here's the script:

```
  > clara1$clustering
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [41] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [81] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[121] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[161] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[201] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[241] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[281] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Here's the size of each cluster

```
> clara1$clusinfo
     size max_diss  av_diss isolation
[1,]   89 1185.879 390.8108 0.1614933
[2,]   93 3211.336 643.9164 0.4373207
[3,]  118 1266.555 501.9639 0.1439830
```

Comment: `euclidean` distance doesn't seem appropriate for categorial data with missing values! **first** find a meaningful similarity measure. Once you have a working similarity, start clustering. The other way around does not work.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse CRAN's cluster pdf said the CLARA function takes tables with missing values and I used the Gower metric for mixed variables. I made the mistake of using Euclidean. The CLARA function looks like it calculates the similarities before clustering. However, the result is still the same as the Euclidean measure. Should I calculate the dissimilarities using the daisy function, then load into CLARA?

Comment: First make sure that the results of the similarity function are as desired. Don't just hope it works, it won't.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, you are right. The CLARA function gave more results than observations. I have a 300 variable dataset, but resulted in 900 observations among 3 clusters. We talked earlier on another thread about using CLARA for this application, but I don't know why the similarity function is not working. I cannot load a daisy matrix into CLARA either. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277999/r-cluster-package-error-daisy-function-long-vectors-argument-11-are-not-supp

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I checked the results from CLARA and every row number corresponds to one of the 3 clusters. I am getting the result because the table is made incorrectly and putting the rows in the same cluster. I am still getting the same result with clusplot().