# Error calculating distances with CLARA function in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am creating a market segmentation of consumers by clustering in 3 categories. I am using the cluster CRAN package with the `CLARA` clustering algorithm.

The data has 12901 observations with 34 variables taking on `ordinal` and `NA` values.

The `ordinal` values do not have the same increments between categories. For example, in the HouseholdIncome column, the categories are "0-15k", "15k-25k", "25k-35k", "35k-50k", "50k-75k", "75k-100k", "100k-125k", "125k-150k", "150k-175k", "175k-200k", "200k-250k", "250k+".

Every row has a least 1 observation.

```
> which(rowSums(is.na(Store2df))==ncol(Store2df))
named integer(0)
```

Here's the first five observations of first seven variables.

```
> head(Store2df, n=5)
    Age Gender HouseholdIncome MaritalStatus PresenceofChildren HomeOwnerStatus HomeMarketValue
1  <NA>   Male            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
2 45-54 Female            <NA>          <NA>               <NA>            <NA>            <NA>
5 45-54 Female        75k-100k       Married                Yes             Own       150k-200k
6 25-34   Male        75k-100k       Married                 No             Own       300k-350k
7 35-44 Female       125k-150k       Married                Yes             Own       250k-300k
```

Here's the code for the clara function:

```
> library(cluster)
> #Clara algorithm
> #Set seed for reproducibility
> set.seed(1)
> #Changing medoids.x and keep.data = TRUE - new way 
> client2.clara <- clara(Store2df, 3, metric = "manhattan", stand = FALSE, samples = 5,
+                        sampsize = (2500), medoids.x = TRUE, keep.data = TRUE, 
+                        rngR = TRUE, pamLike = TRUE)
#Error in clara(Store2df, 3, metric = "manhattan", stand = FALSE, samples = 5,  : 
  #Each of the random samples contains objects between which no distance can be computed.
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

**Source code for CLARA:**

```
ndyst = as.integer(if(metric == "manhattan") 2 else 1),
```

Comment: In the help file, `?clara`, for the argument `x`, it says "`All variables must be numeric. Missing values (NAs) are allowed.`" Are you passing in non-`numeric` variables?

Comment: Obviously he is passing non-numeric values: `MaritalStatus Married` *cannot* be used with Manhattan distance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each of the random samples contains objects between which no distance can be computed.

Take this error message seriously...

`metric = "manhattan"`

is not defined for *categorial* variables.

Manhattan and Euclidean distances operate on *numeric* vectors (which also should be linearly scaled, and e.g. not angles or logscaled).

Comment: I need to connect the last study we were talking about. In this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277999/r-cluster-package-error-daisy-function-long-vectors-argument-11-are-not-supp we talked about CLARA not needing a full distance matrix. However, in this post, we tried plotting, but needed a different distance measure. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272274/error-in-clusplot-function-in-r-missing-values-were-displaced-by-median-of-corr. How can we use a different distance measure with clara? I posted the source code for CLARA above.

Comment: So, have you identified a similarity metric for your data? Before you have found a *working* similarity metric, you won't have success in clustering *for sure*. Don't start with the last step.

Comment: From the code snipped you posted, the implementation of CLARA in R may not support other metrics, unfortunately.

Comment: what if I converted the categorical and NA observations into binary variables? For example, Gender would be Male,Female, and NA converted to (0,0,1),(0,1,0), and (0,0,1).

Comment: A hack that won't do you much good, because it makes NA most similar to NA, and you have a lot of them. First, solve **how to measure similarity** from a **user** perspective, not from a R perspective. Just beause you can code it this way does not mean it helps your analysis. You can code it in a single attribute as 1,2,99, but that won't help either (why is female=2 more similar to NA=99 than male=1?)...